# Reactive Extensions: SubscribeOn take no effect when compose with Publish

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'm new to Reactive Extensions.

I have a room based MMOFPS game server with many rooms and only one listening socket. I create a cold observable which represents messages received from the network, and want to convert it to hot to be shared between multiple rooms so each room can filter and process their relevant messages. Is my approach correct?

Another problem, after converting the cold observable to hot I realized SubscribeOn lost its effect. For example:

```
var observable = Observable.Return(1).Publish(); 
observable 
    .Where( 
        x => 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Filter on {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
                return true; 
            }) 
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread) 
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.NewThread) 
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Received on {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)); 
observable.Connect(); 
Console.WriteLine("End {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
Console.ReadLine();
```

> Result:
>   Received on 12
>   End 10 
>   Filter on 10

Without Publish:

> Result: 
>   End 10 
>   Filter on 11 
>   Received on 12

But when I use Publish.RefCount to auto connect, it works as expected.

Am I missing something? ...

Comment: What are you expecting that `SubscribeOn` will do?

Comment: The chances are that when you change to a socket source for your messages then there won't be a need to make it hot as it already will be.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread) will make the execution of 'Where' on a new thread not current thread. 'End 10' & 'Filter on 10'. It should be difference.

And my socket is not really .Net Socket, I use [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/), and have no chance to access the .Net socket it use. My approach is keep polling Lidgren in background thread for incoming packet and produce an infinity observable.

Is my approach correct? I'm really new to Reactive Extensions.

Comment: You need to use `ObserveOn` rather than `SubscribeOn`. The latter only causes the subscription of the observer to occur on the scheduler provided. The former is where the `Where` will be scheduled on.

Comment: You'll need to use some form of `FromEventPattern`/`FromAyncPattern` to get an observable source of your messages. If you do it this way they will be hot.

Comment: I just try it, and it still not work, nothing different after comment out SubscribeOn(NewThread), my goal is to do the filtering on background thread.

Oop!, is miss your latter comment.

Comment: About FromEventPattern / FromAyncPattern -> I have no event nor socket. I use [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/ReceivingMessages). It only allow poll, callback or blocking wait for incoming messages.

Comment: It uses some non-standard call backs!

Comment: peer.RegisterReceivedCallback(new SendOrPostCallback(GotMessage)); 

public static void GotMessage(object peer)
{
        var msg = peer.ReadMessage();
        // process message here
}

Comment: In that case use a `Subject<Message>` to push out your notifications and perform the `.OnNext(msg)` inside the `GotMessage` callback. It'll be hot then.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer, you will gain rep and help those who come later... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which you apply operators is important.  If you want to share the subscription side-effects of SubscribeOn, then you must apply it before Publish.  For example:

```
var observable = Observable
    .Return(1)
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread)
    .Publish();
```

For more information:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/rx/thread/29de2890-8303-404d-a6f8-f0fe0f716a86